# Why does the second grid not show any of its children? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

To start off I should say I'm not new to programming but very new to XAML so this is probably quite a simple question. I am using visual studio WPF

```
        <Grid x:Name="motivGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="700" Margin="46,200,46,289" Height="100">
            <Label Content="How's your motivation?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="150,0,150,50" FontFamily="Yu Gothic Light" FontSize="30" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="306"/>
            <Slider x:Name="motivSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,48,0,8" Width="700" Height="34" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF5377C5" Background="#FF86F78B" BorderBrush="#FF31B436" Value="-1" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" TickPlacement="Both" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" TickFrequency="0.1"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="energyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="700" Margin="46,320,46,289" Height="100">
            <Label Content="How's your energy levels?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="150,0,150,50" FontFamily="Yu Gothic Light" FontSize="30" Height="50"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="306"/>
            <Slider x:Name="energySlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,48,0,8" Width="700" Height="34" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF5377C5" Background="#FF86F78B" BorderBrush="#FF31B436" Value="-1" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" TickPlacement="Both" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" TickFrequency="0.1"/>
        </Grid>
```

Both grids are exactly the same except for names and y value placements, why is the first grid showing fine but the second has all its elements invisible?

Side note: I am using the grid purely as a container for each slider and label, is there a better equivalent to say HTML's `<div>` function?
I have parent grids that I have not included but work fine and are big enough to allow the missing grid to be shown.

Comment: Does using a Canvas rather than a Grid do what you want. https://wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

Comment: @PaulF urm.. yes! I'll have to do some reading into why though. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Big margins mean bad things like no flow and problems on other displays. You should look into grid columns and rows. Use these for substantial layout. Do not use large margins. Do not drag controls round in the designer - edit in xaml and use the designer for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a Grid to do your layout, you should consider that a Grid consists of some (virtual) cells that can be used to place your controls. Not specifying regarding any information at all will place the elements in the grid in the same cell and you are tempted to arrange the controls by means of coordinates. That will go havoc as soon as screen resolution will change.

The important choices are mentioned in the wpf tutorial link posted by @PaulF, but the information is quite compressed. For your case, I would either keep with nested Grids or use StackPanels.

For the following code I assume you have placed your two grids inside a , then the Grid variant could be like

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="motivGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="How's your motivation?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Yu Gothic Light" FontSize="30" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="306"/>
        <Slider Grid.Row="1" x:Name="motivSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="34" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF5377C5" Background="#FF86F78B" BorderBrush="#FF31B436" Value="-1" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" TickPlacement="Both" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" TickFrequency="0.1"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="energyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0"  Content="How's your energy levels?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Yu Gothic Light" FontSize="30" Height="50"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="306"/>
        <Slider Grid.Row="1" x:Name="energySlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="34" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF5377C5" Background="#FF86F78B" BorderBrush="#FF31B436" Value="-1" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" TickPlacement="Both" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" TickFrequency="0.1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If there is no special reason to have the motivGrid and energyGrid have unique names, the same layout would be archived having just the outermost grid with 4 rows.

Assuming that these grid names are not for other purpose, the alternative could be:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="How's your motivation?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Yu Gothic Light" FontSize="30" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="306"/>
        <Slider x:Name="motivSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="34" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF5377C5" Background="#FF86F78B" BorderBrush="#FF31B436" Value="-1" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" TickPlacement="Both" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" TickFrequency="0.1"/>
        <Label  Content="How's your energy levels?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Yu Gothic Light" FontSize="30" Height="50"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="306"/>
        <Slider x:Name="energySlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="34" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF5377C5" Background="#FF86F78B" BorderBrush="#FF31B436" Value="-1" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" TickPlacement="Both" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" TickFrequency="0.1"/>
</StackPanel>
```